# Is Document.cookie's setter asynchronous in web browsers?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am under the impression that `document.cookie = "mySessionCookie=mySessionToken"` does not get set right away in the browser.

More precisely, here's my situation:

- I am logged in.
- I want to logout using Javascript.
- So I set, for instance `document.cookie = "mySessionCookie=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"`.
- Then I call `window.location.reload()` to confirm that I have been logged out.

It mostly works, but, quite often, it appears that the browser does not have enough time to set my new cookie value before calling `window.location.reload()`.

Unless I am doing something wrong in my code, that behaviour suggests that `document.cookie = "value"` is not executed on the same stack (so, it might not be asynchronous by itself, but it has an unpredictable behaviour when used with the rest of the code).

So, my question is, could `document.cookie = "value"` be executed on a different stack?

Comment: No...javascript is single threaded and setting  cookie is synchronous. More likely your issue is something else

Comment: @charlietfl, thank you for confirming this. There must be something wrong with my code then.

Answer (score 11):

Indeed, as pointed out by @charlietfl as a comment to my original question, the `document.cookie` setter will set the cookie right away.

My real problem was that I had an error in my program, where I was not paying attention to the fact that browsers will set the cookie's "path" based on the current URI when no path is provided along with the cookie value when setting a cookie using JavaScript.

For example, if one wants to clear a session for all URIs at `example.com` while viewing a resource at `http://example.com/fake-resource`, one must explicitly write:

`document.cookie = "sessionToken=;Path=/;Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"`

else (i.e. if Path=/ is omitted) the browser will create a second cookie for `example.com/fake-resource`, such that the main cookie will continue to exist.

Comment: oh  my god you rescued me from cookie hell. Thankyou!